# Installion Wizard that Checks for Python

Tags: python, installation, exe, wizard

So is there an installation wizard out there that can be used to installed a python program as a exe, with a desktop icon, and that check if the user has python 2.7+ installed on their computer.

I am writing a small application and it is 10x faster to write in python than java. I know java, but as a diehard python fan I would rather help the cause of python.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the actual program as an exe file, you won't need actually have python installed on that computer. This is called 'freezing' your code. Here is a good article about some common tools to accomplish that: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/shipping/freezing/.

These programs will also allow you set an icon for the .exe file. For example pyinstaller you include the line "--icon=FILE.ICO" in it's specs file http://www.pyinstaller.org/static/docs/Manual_v1.1.html#create-a-spec-file-for-your-project.